# SwiftUI Drag & Drop - NSInternalInconsistencyException: Could not get the cell at indexPath

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have implemented drag & drop between two lists in SwiftUI. Regular drag and drops work fine when dropping it in between list items, but when I do some more advanced drag like dragging it onto the cell itself, my app crashes.
This crash happens even before I drop it (so while I am still dragging it, without releasing drop)

Has anyone occurred this crash ? Is this a SwiftUI bug or am I doing something wrong ?

I have tried removing my code blocks inside `dropDestination`s and yet crash still exists, so what could I be doing wrong ?

Here is the gif of the crash (crash occurs right after I drag it onto the second cell, without dropping/releasing it):

[image: Crash reproduction]

**Code inside dropDestination does not even get called.**

**SwiftUI Code**

```
var body2: some View {
HStack {
  VStack {
    Text("title-pending")
    
    List {
      ForEach(viewModel.pendingOrders) { order in
        RestaurantOrderCardView(order: order) {
          .background(cardBackground)
          .draggable(order)
      }
      .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
      .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
      .padding(.top)
    }
    .listStyle(.plain)
    .background(listBackground)
  }
  
  VStack {
    Text("title-in-preparation")
    
    List {
      ForEach(viewModel.inPreparationOrders) { item in
        RestaurantOrderCardView(order: item)
          .background(cardBackground)
      }
      .dropDestination(for: RestaurantOrder.self) { items, offset in
        guard let firstItem = items.first else { return }
        withAnimation {
          viewModel.dropItem(firstItem, offset: offset)
        }
      }
      .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
      .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
      .padding(.top)
    }
    .listStyle(.plain)
    .background {
      if !viewModel.inPreparationOrders.isEmpty {
        listBackground
      }
    }
    .overlay {
      if viewModel.inPreparationOrders.isEmpty {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
          .foregroundColor(!inDropArea ? .grayBackgroundColor : .grayBackgroundColor.opacity(0.25))
          .ignoresSafeArea()
          .dropDestination(for: RestaurantOrder.self) { items, location in
            guard let firstItem = items.first else { return false }
            withAnimation {
              viewModel.dropItem(firstItem, offset: 0)
            }
            return true
          } isTargeted: { inDropArea in
            withAnimation {
              self.inDropArea = inDropArea
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

**Crash Log**

```
2023-01-06 11:25:05.995303+0100 SimplifyStayAdmin[78761:2158775] *** Assertion failure in -[_UICollectionViewDragAndDropController _beginDragAndDropInsertingItemAtIndexPath:], _UICollectionViewDragAndDropController.m:620

2023-01-06 11:25:06.074407+0100 SimplifyStayAdmin[78761:2158775] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not get the cell at indexPath <NSIndexPath: 0x8846e25efd6dfbf1> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0} to start the reording portion of the Drag-and-drop'

*** First throw call stack:

(

    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018040e7c8 __exceptionPreprocess + 172

    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000180051144 objc_exception_throw + 56

    2   Foundation                          0x0000000180b13b98 _userInfoForFileAndLine + 0

    3   UIKitCore                           0x0000000109a546ec -[_UICollectionViewDragAndDropController _beginDragAndDropInsertingItemAtIndexPath:] + 540

    4   UIKitCore                           0x0000000109a53064 -[_UICollectionViewDragAndDropController beginReorderingForItemAtIndexPath:cell:] + 204

    5   UIKitCore                           0x0000000109a1bad0 -[UICollectionView _beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath:] + 196

    6   UIKit                               0x000000011803040c -[UICollectionViewAccessibility beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath:] + 80

    7   UIKitCore                           0x0000000109a5c55c -[_UICollectionViewDragDestinationController _reorderingDisplayLinkDidTick] + 912

    8   QuartzCore                          0x0000000187dd04f8 _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy + 808

    9   QuartzCore                          0x0000000187ec89a8 _ZL22display_timer_callbackP12__CFMachPortPvlS1_ + 336

    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018033ee94 __CFMachPortPerform + 172

    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018037387c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56

    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180372e9c __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 496

    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018036d43c __CFRunLoopRun + 2176

    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018036c7a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584

    15  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000188ff7c98 GSEventRunModal + 160

    16  UIKitCore                           0x000000010a1f237c -[UIApplication _run] + 868

    17  UIKitCore                           0x000000010a1f6374 UIApplicationMain + 124

    18  SwiftUI                             0x000000010e6150d4 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_51 + 496

    19  SwiftUI                             0x000000010e614f7c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_51 + 152

    20  SwiftUI                             0x000000010dd7ab60 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_10 + 88

    21  SimplifyStayAdmin                   0x000000010044d0c4 $s17SimplifyStayAdmin0abC3AppV5$mainyyFZ + 40

    22  SimplifyStayAdmin                   0x000000010044d378 main + 12

    23  dyld                                0x00000001080c1fa0 start_sim + 20

    24  ???                                 0x00000001081c9e50 0x0 + 4431060560

    25  ???                                 0x0869800000000000 0x0 + 606156362346397696

)

libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not get the cell at indexPath <NSIndexPath: 0x8846e25efd6dfbf1> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0} to start the reording portion of the Drag-and-drop'

terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

CoreSimulator 857.14 - Device: iPad (10th generation) (D79A0AD8-4970-4F84-A5F9-078DAFB697A3) - Runtime: iOS 16.2 (20C52) - DeviceType: iPad (10th generation)
```

Comment: Can you try moving `.dropDestination` outside `List` instead of `ForEach`?

Comment: It would not suit me, because `List` does not have `.dropDestination` modifier with offset, and also that smooth animations of moving items in list

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this seems to work, but in a similar project getting a similar error, I changed the line

> .dropDestination(for: RestaurantOrder.self) { items, **location** in

to

> .dropDestination(for: RestaurantOrder.self) { items, **_** in

and that seems to have stopped the crashes (at least so far). In my case, the crashes were somewhat intermittent, and so I couldn't predict that one would occur at an exact, specific point during a drag, but they seemed to happen with some frequency. And since replacing "location" with "_" I've not seen one.

I can only point to the most vague intuition of "let's try *this*" as to why that particular change was even worth trying, but if this solution helps somebody out, then that's a good thing.